# How can I view my site from outside my network? I'm using nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, raspberry-pi, server

I am trying to run a website off of a raspberry pi using nginx. I have port-forwarded to port 8080, and allowed for that port in my firewall. I can access the site on my LAN no problem, but I get an error message when trying to access the site from a computer outside my network.  [isup.me](http://isup.me) says my site is up, however any proxy server says it is not allowed to view sites from my ip. my nginx.conf file is as follows:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    client_body_timeout   10;
     keepalive_timeout     10 10;
    send_timeout          10;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;


    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

     gzip_min_length   1100;
     gzip_vary on;
     gzip_proxied any;
     gzip_comp_level 6;
     gzip_buffers 16 8k;
     gzip_http_version 1.1;
     gzip_types  text/plain text/css applciation/jsonapplication/xjavascript
     text/xml applcation/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript 
     images/svg+xml application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-
     fontobject;                                           
    ##
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

}

And here is my $sites-available/thomaswurdinger.com configuration (which is softlinked to $sites-enabled/thomaswurdinger.com):

```
server {
    listen  8080; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /websites/thomaswurdinger/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name thomaswurdinger.com www.thomaswurdinger.com;
    error_log /websites/thomaswurdinger/logs/error.log error;
    access_log /websites/thomaswurdinger/logs/access.log;
     location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
    }

    location ~\.php$ {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;

if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
    return 404;
}
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
include fastcgi_params;
}
```

My domain name is registered with namecheap, and it is forwarding traffic to 192.168.0.7:8080 using redirect. Please help.

Comment: From outside your LAN you need a public and static IP address -- do you have one? 192.168.x.x is only for private LAN addresses and you won't be able to access it from outside.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by this.  I have set the ip address to static and even have namecheap redirecting to port 8080.  I had it working for a short while on 192.168.0.4, but then I messed it up somehow.

Comment: See my answer below and see if your setup checks out. For your DNS setup, you just need an A record mapping your domain name to your WAN static IP (you do not need namecheap to redirect).

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that you can access your site from inside your LAN, the problem may have to do with your router/firewall setup to proxy to your RaspberryPi server.

You should:

- Double-check and make sure your domain (thomaswurdinger.com/www.thomaswurdinger.com) is mapped to your WAN static IP address (i.e. has an A record with your WAN static IP mapped to the domain name).
- Configure your router/firewall to direct all incoming traffic from your WAN on port 8080 to your Rpi server at 192.168.0.7 (or whatever IP your Rpi device is using). Obviouly, you want also to make sure the firewall is accepting and not blocking TCP connections on port 8080.

The 192.168.0.x IP address is only usable from inside your LAN.

From outside, use:

- http://www.thomaswurdinger.com:8080

#### Interface setup on your RaspberryPi

Assuming your Rpi is running a Debian-based OS like "Rasbian," your `/etc/network/interfaces` should contain the static IP for your Rpi server:

```
iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.0.7
      netmask 255.255.255.0
```

That is all your need to make sure the server has a static IP inside your LAN. It should be accessible from inside your LAN.

But note that the 192.168.x.x range of addresses are only used for private, internal networks. See the following article on Wikipedia for more details:  [Private network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). They are not accessible from ourside your LAN.

#### Router/firewall setup to allow connections to your Rpi server

To allow access to your LAN server (the Rpi server at 192.168.0.7), you should configure your router/firewall to allow requests coming in from your WAN to your LAN:

```
WAN (Internet) -> request -> router/firewall -> redirect to 192.168.0.7
```

How to configure your router/firewall depends on what device you have -- it could be a small modem/router from your ISP, an Apple Extreme, or a heavy-weight Cisco/HP router, etc. Usually you can configure your router (which also works as a firewall) using some sort of web-based interface.

You should make sure to have a firewall rule that says any **TCP** request coming in to the destination port of **8080** gets redirected to **192.168.0.7** (which is your RaspberryPi).

#### DNS setup to map your domain to your WAN static IP address

Assuming your have a static WAN IP address -- say, for example, `11.22.33.44` -- you should map your domain name to the IP at your registrar's DNS records. It should be something like this (this is just an example domain and IP -- substitute your real ones):

```
yourdomain.com.   1800   IN  A   11.22.33.44
www.yourdomain.com.   1800   IN  A   11.22.33.44
```

(Use namecheap.com's web-based DNS host records dashboard to modify your A records.)

(If you don't have a static IP from your service provider, your may be out of luck. There are services that provide dynamic dns but I have not used those.)

All this **assumes** your nginx setup is working correctly. So the problem with your setup is not really about the nginx but lies in your DNS and router/firewall configurations.

Comment: I want to thank you, kchan, for giving me a hand.  I want to let you know that I am a complete novice when it comes to servers.  I'll admit I get a bit confused when talking about where my WAN and internal ip address point.  As it stands now, Do I need the WAN ip address in my /etc/network/interfaces file anywhere? `auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
`

Comment: Also, when I try to access my site through a free proxy server like [https://hide.me/en/proxy], It tells me it's not allowed to view sites from 192.168.0.7.  Again, at some point, it did work on (internal ip) 192.168.0.4 for several days.

Comment: @Thomas -- I have updated the answer with additional explanations and pseudo code. Please see if that makes sense.

Comment: O.k. I think I am missing a command for my firewall rules.  I don't think I have it set up to forward any requests to port 8080.  Could you look at them please:`*filter

#  Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

#  Accept all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#  Allow all outbound traffic - you can modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT



`

Comment: `#  Allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites and SSL).
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT


#  Allow SSH connections
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

#  Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

#  Log iptables denied calls
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

#  Drop all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
COMMIT
`

Comment: Are you using a Linux box as your router? You want to make sure in your rules to handle incoming traffic you have something like this: `iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.0.7 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: I think we're on the right track, but it gives me this error when resetting the rules:Bad argument '–'
Error occurred at line: 17
Try iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.

`

Comment: Try typing the iptables rules on your router's terminal: `iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.0.7 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT` and test the connection

Comment: For your router's iptables setup, you may want to post a new question (possibly on serverfault.com) so the question will be specifically about that part of your setup. It's difficult to troubleshoot this kind of thing through comments since the formatting runs everything together.